# Why can't my .net core xunit test find my appsettings.json?

Tags: c#, selenium, xunit, appsettings

I am new to testing/development.  I have created a x unit test project in .net core for testing the UI of my website using selenium.  My file structure looks like this [image: file]

This is my appsettings.json:

```
{
  "Base_Url": "https://pretendurl/",
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

This is my test class:

```
using Xunit;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using System;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System.Configuration;

namespace XUnitTestProject1.UI.Tests
{
    public class HomePageShould
    {
        [Fact]
        public void LoadHomepage()
        {

            using IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            var settings = new ConfigurationBuilder()
               .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
               .Build();

            var homeUrl = settings["Base_Url"];
            
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(homeUrl);

        }
    }
}
```

I get this error: The configuration file 'appsettings.json' was not found and is not optional.  My test project is in a separate repo from the system I am testing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to update the `XUnitTestProject1.UI.Tests.csproj` to export your appsettings to the build folder.

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="appsettings.Test.json" CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

You should reate a separate `appsettings.Test.json` file in your test project with your test settings, and the code above will copy it to the build folder.

Answer (score 0):

Change the 'Copy to output folder' property of the json file in VS. It needs to be copied to the output folder where the app will run.